# Why is "He said me he was ..." ungrammatical, but "He told me he was ..." is not?

Tags: licensing

> a.1) He *said* he was moving to New York. 
>   a.2) *He *said* **me** he was moving
>   to New York.
>
> b.1) *He *told* he was moving to New York. 
>   b.2) He *told* **me** he was moving
>   to New York.

Why is a.2) wrong, but b.2) is right?

Can anybody explain what the difference between these verbs (*say, tell*) is, obviously with regard to the rule, if any, for which "me" has to be omitted in a.1) but not in b.2).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both *say* and *tell* are transitive verbs: they take as their objects the utterance quoted (in direct speech) or paraphrased (in indirect speech).

The difference is that *tell* in most cases requires an *indirect object*, the hearer of the utterance (it is like *give* in this respect), which may be expressed with or without a preposition. With *say* the *indirect object* is optional, and must be expressed with a prepositional phrase:

> He told *me* that.  He told that *to* me.
>   He said that *to me*.

However, *tell* does not require an indirect object when used with certain *direct objects*:

> He told the story/history/tale/joke.

Answer (score 0):

As you know **say** and **tell** are very similar in meaning. Stoney B has given a very good grammatical explanation already, but when you speak it's sometimes easier to think in terms of what you want to say.

Since the grammar has already been explained, I'll just give a couple of examples of what I mean.

> With the veb **say**, the focus is on **what is said** or **the information**.
>
> Example: He said the movie was amazing.

In this example, we can only assume he was talking to the speaker. But it's very possible he was talking to someone else, and the speaker simply heard him. The focus here is on the information. It must come *directly after the verb* ***say***.

> With the veb **tell**, the focus is on **whom we tell** or **the listener**.
>
> Example: He told his students they had homework.

In this example, the information is present, but the most important part is the listeners, the students. When we use tell, the person or people to whom we are talking must come *directly after the verb* ***tell***.

Answer (score -1):

Well, both ***told*** & ***said*** are used in narration.

Mostly, ***Said*** is used, when somebody narrating the monologue of the speech held in the past.
eg> The leader said that ……………………….

And, ***Told*** is used, when somebody narrating the dialogue of the conversation held in the past.
eg> The boss told me that …………………….

However, today’s trends  are using both the words as replica to each other.

Comment: No, today's trend is *not* to use these words interchangeably, except among people who don't speak English very well.