# Why can't we say "explain me it" or "say me it"?

Tags: complementation, objects, licensing

By putting the direct object before the indirect object we can say:

> - tell it to me
> - say it to me
> - explain it to me

And if we put the indirect object before the direct object we can say:

> - tell me it

But not:

> - say me it
> - explain me it

Why is this?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/57947/

Comment: Related: [Why is “He said me …” ungrammatical, but “He told me …” is not?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/705/357)

Answer (score 4):

First, a small but important correction: *me* in *Say/tell/explain X to me* plays the same **semantic** role as bare *me* in *Tell me X*—both *me*'s are Recipients—but it has a different **syntactic role**. Bare *me* is an Indirect Object, but *me* in *to me* is not an object of the verb—it's an object of the preposition *to*. Some grammarians call this *me* an *oblique*.

So a first-order answer to your question is “because *tell* is ditransitive—it is permitted (but not required) to take two objects, while *say* and *explain* are monotransitive—they are permitted to take only one object (each).”

That of course is just a *name* for the phenomenon, not a true *because*; but you're rarely going to get actual *becauses* in matters of this sort. Language is a democracy; we've been voting on these uses of those three words continuously for over a thousand years (well, only about 600 in the case of *explain*), and the only one of the three that got a majority of votes for ditransitivity is *tell*.

In other words, it's that way because we like it that way.

(My personal theory is that this Reign of Linguistic Terror came about shortly after the Norman Conquest, when the suppressed *witenagemot*, the Englisc proto-parliament, met in secret and launched a centuries-long project to make the Englisc language unintelligible to non-native speakers, so no one would ever be tempted to conquer the Anglo-Saxons again. But the evidence is wholly circumstantial.)

Comment: Re your last comment, do you mean like Cockney rhyming slang?

Comment: @CJDennis I was thinking more of use of the definite article and modal verbs.

Answer (score 0):

*Say* and *explain* don't work with two objects for some reason (I don't know what that reason is).  *Tell* does, however.

So if you want to express that *say X* or *explain X* is happening "toward" someone, you have to explicitly use a preposition with the person or thing the activity is happening "toward."