# Consider them to be smart...but Say them to be smart?

Tags: grammaticality

If we can say: He **is considered (to be)** smart. We **consider him (to be)** smart.

By the same token, I have also heard: We **think him (to be)** smart or think him dead.

It is also correct to say: He **is said to be** smart.

*But, Is it correct to say???*: We **say him to be** smart.

For some reason it appears to follow the above structures, but sounds very strange.

Comment: We say: _We say that he is smart._

Comment: Related, but maybe the title needs to change it was really hard to find: [Why is “He said me he was …” ungrammatical, but “He told me he was …” is not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/705/why-is-he-said-me-he-was-ungrammatical-but-he-told-me-he-was-is-not) Also related: ['Say' and 'Tell' difference!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67738/say-and-tell-difference)

Comment: @Mari-LouA. Not exactly related. I am well aware that "to say someone something" is ungrammatical. The meaning here was not as in "to tell someone (to someone)", but as in "to know someone (of someone)".

Comment: Related does not mean that the two questions are identical with yours. The answers simply point out that an object pronoun (me, you, him, her, it, us, them) is commonly used with the verb "tell".

Comment: The meaning of "We say him to be smart" is *NOT* "We have heard that he is smart". "We say" means "we speak/communicate" But fortunately, your comment has clarified why you are asking and your confusion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Can you explain to me why these old questions get pushed to the head of the queue? Is it because no answer was chosen?

Comment: Because even if an  answer has been posted, unless it is upvoted the question is considered "unanswered" and the system periodically bumps them to the home page.

Answer (score 1):

In standard English usage, the verb *say* can have as its object either a literal utterance, a noun phrase, or a subordinate clause. But even in the last two cases, the object must refer to at least a figurative utterance. Four examples:

```
 1. He glanced up and said, "No thank you."     [an utterance]
 2. She lowered her head and said grace.        [a noun phrase]
 3. He says that he'll do it.                   [a subordinate clause]
 4. Her facial expression said she was fed up.
```

In example 4 the object is a subordinate clause (with the conjunction *that* left out). And the utterance is only figurative: Her facial expression conveyed her exasperation as though it could speak, and if so it would say, "I'm fed up."

When it comes, as in your example, to expressing the opinion that someone is smart, the closest might be things like

```
 We declare him to be smart.
```

or

```
 We proclaim him to be smart.
```

But each of those has at least a suggestion of a [speech act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act)

Comment: +1 Interesting you should mention "speech act". I consider a lot of things happening here performative utterances (as per J.L. Austin). For example: up/downvotes, +1.

Answer (score 0):

In speech, the most common way to express  this is:

**We say he is smart**.

**"We say him to be smart." is not idiomatic English.**

Question re: "We think him (to be) smart or think him dead." is OK but it is somewhat literary, and somewhat BrE. It generally would not be used in contemporary AmE speech. But it is found in novels and older publications.

Think [someone] [adjective] is OK.

Generally, though, smart in British English means well dressed or well turned out.